# Spring HATEOAS: Practicable for a microservice architecture?

Tags: spring, rest, microservices, spring-hateoas

I know this question was already asked but I could not find a satisfying answer.
I started to dive deeper in building a real restful api and I like it's contraint of using links for decoupling. So I built my first service ( with java / spring ) and it works well ( although I struggled a bit with finding the right format but that's another question ). After this first step I thought about my real world use case. Micorservices. Highly decoupled individual services. So I made a my previous scenario and I came to some problems or doubts.

**SCENARIO:**

My setup consists of a reverse proxy ( Traefik which works as service discovery and api gateway) and 2 Microservices. In addition, there is an openid connect security layer. My services are a Player service and a Team service.

So after auth I have an access token with the userId and I am able to call `player/userId` to get the player information and `teams?playerId=userId` to get all the teams of the player.

In my opinion, I would in both responses link the opposite service. The `player/userId` would link to the `teams?playerId=userId` and vice versa.

**QUESTION:**

I haven't found a solution besides linking via a hardcoded url. But this comes with so many downfalls as I can't imagine that this a solution used in real world applications. I mean just imagine your api is a bit more advanced and you have to link to 10 resources. If something changes, you have refactor and redeploy them all.
Besides the synchonization problem, how do you handle state in such a case. I mean, REST is all about state transfer. So I won't offer the link of the player to teams service if the player is in no team. Of course I can add the team ids as attribute to the player to decide whether to include the link or not. But this again increases coupling between the services.
The more I dive in the more obstacles I find and I'm about to just stay with my spring rest docs and neglect the core of Rest which I is a pity to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Practicable for a microservice architecture?

[Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction.

[Fielding 2008](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742)

> REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations.

It is not immediately clear to me that "microservices" are going to fall into the sweet spot of "the web".  We're not, as a rule, tring to communicate with a microservice that is controlled by another company, we often don't get a lot of benefit out of caching, or code on demand, or the other rest architectural constraints.  How important is it to us that we can use general purpose components to exchange information between different microservices within our solution? and so on.

> If something changes, you have refactor and redeploy them all.

Yes; and if that's going to be a problem for us, then we need to invest more work up front to define a stable interface between the two.  (The fact that we are using "links" isn't special in that regard - if these two things are going to talk to each other, then they are going to need to speak a common language; if that common language needs to evolve over time (likely) then you need to build those capabilities into it).

If you want change over time, then you have to plan for it.

If you want backwards/forwards compatibility, then you have to plan for it.

Your identifiers don't need to be static - there are lots of possible ways of deferring the definition of an identifier; the most obvious being that you can use another identifier to look up the identifier you want, or the formula for calculating it, or whetever.

Think about how Google works - the links they use change all the time, but it doesn't matter because the protocol (refresh your bookmarked search form, enter your text in "the" one field, click the button) hasn't changed in 20 years.  The interface is stable (even though the underlying spellings of the identifiers is not) and that's enough.